# Can I use Writer2LaTeX and the `mla-paper` style together?

Tags: macros, header-footer, xml, mla-style, open-office

I use LibreOffice 4.1.3.x, and have had success using a [patched version of Writer2LaTex](https://sourceforge.net/p/writer2latex/discussion/919907/thread/869db8c5/) with documents created in LibreOffice Writer.

I want to create a (sub?)filter for Writer2LaTeX that allows me to designate fields in my ODT document that correspond to the header fields in Ryan Aycock's `mla-paper` style. Otherwise, the header I create will be superseded by the default `mla-paper` header.

I want to be able to tag a MLA header like the one below<sup>1</sup>--one I create in LibreOffice Writer--so that it easily ports into `mla-paper`'s presets for the header.

```
Phillip H. Vollman                                                                 Vollman 1
Prof. Erika T. Lin
ENGH 426 001
30 March 2014
                                 1 Henry IV Response Paper
```

The intended header in the exported .tex file based on the `mla-paper` style is as follows:

```
\begin{mla}{Phillip H.}{Vollman}{Prof. Erika T. Lin}{ENGH 426 001}{30 March 2014}{1 Henry IV
Response Paper}
```

How would I go about doing this?

<sub>1: *Shakespeare in Performance*'s a great class...</sub>